# Mailto that autopopulates the To: field with original sender

Tags: html, email, mailto, unsubscribe

I'd like to know if the following is actually possible:

A mailto link that does not contain an email address, but somehow auto populates the TO: field with the email of the original sender.

For example:

"a href="mailto:**ORIGINALSENDER**?subject=UNSUBSCRIBE&body=I would like to unsubscribe from future emails">Click here to send an unsubscribe email /a"

Is this possible without having to specify an email address in the link itself? Is there a class or function i can call to autopopulate the To: field?

The reason i ask is we send out curated email templates to individual customers and they are sent via a specific system. This system does not have an unsubscribe function, unfortunately. I am not able to use or suggest a system that does as i am but a lowly cog in the corporate machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no, not dynamically in an email that I'm aware of. Are you sending from the same email address each time? Can you set up an additional email address to handle unsubscribes and just have that hardcoded? (i.e. unsubscribe@yourdomain.com and have that monitored)

If you're using different email addresses, then consider replacing 'click here to unsubscribe' with something to the effect of 'to unsubscribe, reply to this email with unsubscribe in the subject line'

Lastly, making a recommendation and giving a good argument for using a system that better suits your requirements is a first step towards being more than a lowly cog in the corporate machine :)

Comment: No, we are not sending from the same address, i.e, many employees may send email to many different customers, so there is no central point to reply to. The system used can log replies but it doesnt have an unsubscribe function.
Thanks!